# Dart implicit upcast generics warning?

Tags: dart

The following code compiles in Dart with no errors or warnings but will fail at runtime. Is there any way to opt in to warnings for implicit upcasting of generics in Dart?

```
List<Object> objects = <int>[]; // implicit generic upcast
objects.add('hello'); // runtime error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'value'
```

I already have `implicit-casts: false` in my analysis_options.yaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no static analysis available today. The tracking issue discussing this problem, with some proposed solutions linked, is https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/213

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the right terminology to search for that issue. I feel like there is a strong implication that "Dart 2 is type sound so type errors can always be found through static analysis". I don't see anything in the documentation that would lead me to believe otherwise. And I think that will be a common expectation for people with experience in any strongly typed language.